# gfortran doesn't understand C style comments?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, rhel

I am trying to compile the WRF package, which is mostly written in fortran.

Most of the files in this package has a preamble using C-style "/* … */" comments. Unfortunately, when compiling, I have been receiving these errors frequently:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
../dyn_em/module_big_step_utilities_em.f90:2.3:
```

I believe my gfortran version simply does not understand these type of comments, and is failing. I find this very odd since I downloaded the compiler using "yum install" on Red Hat 7.

Could someone please enlighten me??

Comment: @Mike W: The packaged program came like this. I did not write it. There are literally 1000s of .f90, .f, .f77 programs in this package that have these lines. Please answer next time, or don't input at all.

Comment: WRF has its own build system with extensive use of the preprocessor. You shouldn't compile it by any other way.

Comment: @VladimirF: I used its own ./compile system. Still reported this problem.

Comment: Where did you add the `-cpp` flag then?

Comment: I edited the configure.wrf gfortran variable to `gfortran -cpp`

Comment: This feels very wrong though @VladimirF, I still feel like it should compile without my intervention. Could this be a ./configure problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a valid way of delineating comments for standard Fortran.

I suspect the code expects to be preprocessed by a C preprocessor, many of which would replace comments like that with white space.

Try running gfortran with the -cpp option.